# Multiple *jus soli*

Tags: legal-history, citizenship

Until a few years ago, birth in Northern Ireland conferred citizenship in *two* states: the UK and Ireland.

Was this unique in modern history, or are there other similar examples?

Comment: I was wondering about situations like an aircraft flagged in one country flying through the airspace of another...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes includes several regions where both claimants have *jus soli* citizenship.  In some cases there are even three, e.g. a baby born in [Sapodilla Cayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapodilla_Cayes) could conceivably get Belizean, Guatemalan and Honduran citizenship at birth.  Bajo Nuevo Bank and Serranilla Bank are each claimed by *four* nations, but only three of them have *jus soli* (Colombia does not).

Comment: Most of these are theoretical because the regions are uninhabited, and so most likely nobody has been born there in modern history.

Comment: @NateEldredge usually, rules granting nationality to a child born in an airplane or on a ship of the state of registration apply only if the child would otherwise be stateless.

Comment: "Until a few years ago, birth in Northern Ireland conferred citizenship in two states: the UK and Ireland." The UK has not had unconditional jus soli since 1983, and the Republic of Ireland has not had unconditional jus soli since 2005. Those are not "a few years ago".

Comment: Is it like that for Puerto Rico?

Comment: @MichaelHall: What do you mean?  Children born in Puerto Rico are citizens of the United States at birth, and not of any other independent country (except possibly through other citizenships that their parents may hold).  There is a notion of [Puerto Rican citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Rican_citizenship_and_nationality) but its exact legal significance seems ambiguous.  I suppose you could also say that being born in San Francisco confers both US and California citizenship, but I don't think that's the point of the question.

Comment: @NateEldredge, i used a question mark because im uncertain.  But it is a nation, and territory, not a state.  Presuming dual citizenship is possible. Thought it might be a good example to steer the OP towards an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require that a country grant jus soli to an area outside its control, which often involves a territorial dispute, as Nate Eldredge's comment mentioned. Many territorial disputes are over small, often uninhabited areas, but some are not.

One territorial dispute that comes to mind is the Falkland Islands -- Argentina is jus soli, and the UK was jus soli until 1983 (and British overseas citizens were later granted full British citizenship). So someone born in the Falkland Islands in 1983 is now both a British citizen and Argentine citizen, regardless of the status of the parents, according to each country.

Another example is the territorial claims in Antarctic, of which the UK, Chilean, and Argentine claims overlap. Argentina has jus soli; Chile has jus soli except that it is not automatic for children of transient foreigners, but they may opt for Chilean citizenship; and the UK had jus soli before 1983. So someone born in the area overlapped by all 3 claims will have Argentine citizenship and can opt for Chilean citizenship (though they would likely only opt for Chilean citizenship if they were part of a Chilean family), and if born before 1983 will also have British citizenship.

It is possible that, if and when the territorial dispute is resolved, there might be some provision regarding the citizenship of people born during the dispute. Perhaps a country giving up claim on a portion of territory will retroactively invalidate the jus soli citizenship of people born in that area. Or perhaps the people will have to choose one of the two jus soli to keep. Or perhaps they will be able to keep both unless they choose to renounce one. It is up to the countries involved.

Comment: Have there actually been instances in history where a country revoked the citizenship of some of its own citizens as part of a treaty, when those citizens had not otherwise done anything wrong?  It seems like a pretty extreme step, and maybe unconstitutional in many cases.

Comment: @NateEldredge “their own citizens” Is rather begging the question, no? I doubt any treaty ever led to citizenship being forcibly revoked, but following the Velvet Divorce citizens had a year to opt for Czech or Slovak citizenship. I suspect that’s not an uncommon pattern, where citizens are free to choose their citizenship but may not retain both.

Comment: @NateEldredge it seems as though a country giving up territory can take a few different approaches to its citizens residing there: retain citizenship no matter what, retain citizenship only if leaving the territory, and lose citizenship no , matter what.  I imagine you can find examples of each fairly easily.

Comment: @Sneftel: I mean it in the sense of "people who had been considered citizens up to that point in time".  The Czech/Slovak citizenship issue is interesting.  I suppose in some sense it meant that everyone had their Czechoslovakian citizenship revoked, but that was for the simple reason that Czechoslovakia ceased to exist.

Comment: @phoog: It's the third one that I would find surprising.  I'm not sure where I would look for an example.

Comment: @NateEldredge before the advent of nationstates, you would automatically loose your citizenship in a hanseatic city if moved your center of living to any other town. But you would not gain citizenship by moving in... but then again, there was no "jus solis" then, but kids would gain their citizenship status by simply aging up.

Comment: @NateEldredge the population of the Philippines had US nationality (not citizenship, but that doesn't seem particularly significant for the purpose of this discussion) and the vast majority lost it, though I do not know under what terms. Did all residents of Alaska have the opportunity to move to Russia when the US took it over? What happened to the residents of Alsace and Lorraine as they changed hands several times? If you go far enough back in time you'll surely find an example where the population had no choice; is it so far back as to predate the modern concept of nationality?

Comment: Thank you, the Falkland Islands is a great example. Apparently there are some rare examples of Falkland Islanders accepting Argentine citizenship, so this isn’t merely theoretical: https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/falkland-islander-who-took-argentine-citizenship-seeks-peace-7r2c0f750qk